# Create Class Store Objects

Tags: java, arrays, class, store

I have a beginner question about Objects and storing them. I need to create a separate class called **GameEntry** with one attribute called **scores**, then I need to store these **GameEntry** Objects in an Array. Not just any Array though it has to be the one with the square brackets: [ ]

Weirdly, I can get it working using `ArrayList` but using a simple Array is like mission impossible?? Can anyone help?

```
class GameEntry {
    int scores;

    GameEntry(int s) {
        scores = s;
    }
}

public class R11ScoreArray {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameEntry[] scoreArray; // declares that scoreArray is an array of
                            // 'GameEntry'
        scoreArray = new GameEntry[4]; // create array of 4 elements
        scoreArray[0] = new GameEntry(10);
        scoreArray[0] = new GameEntry(100);
        scoreArray[0] = new GameEntry(1000);
        scoreArray[0] = new GameEntry(10000);
        for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scoreArray));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your snippet for the array.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and where exactly you have difficulties. What exactly isn't working? Did you research on how to create custom objects and how to create arrays? It should be something like `RaceCar[] cars = new RaceCar[10];` for an array with place for `10` `RaceCar` objects.

Comment: Thanks. But please include it in your question by **editing** it.

Comment: What is your expected output, what is the current output? If there is an error message, what does it read?

Comment: Managed to edit my question, phew.

Comment: [GameEntry@15db9742, null, null, null]
[GameEntry@15db9742, null, null, null]
[GameEntry@15db9742, null, null, null]
[GameEntry@15db9742, null, null, null]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Explanation

I think you slightly misunderstood how to work with arrays. Creating arrays works like this

```
GameEntry[] scoreArray = new GameEntry[4];
```

this array is now able to hold `4` `GameEntry` objects. It is short for

```
// Declare
GameEntry[] scoreArray;

// Allocate
scoreArray = new GameEntry[4];
```

You set and access those objects by using their **index**, like this

```
// Set the first object, at index 0
scoreArray[0] = new GameEntry(10);

// Set the second object, at index 1
scoreArray[1] = new GameEntry(100);

// Access the first object
System.out.println(scoreArray[0].scores);

// Access the second object
System.out.println(scoreArray[1].scores);
```

Also your print statement doesn't make much sense:

```
for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(scoreArray));
}
```

It stringifies the whole array, in every iteration again. So why should it be included inside a loop? You probably intended to iterate the array and access the elements manually. The `Arrays.toString` method already iterates the array by itself. It's like asking `4` times the same question *"how does the complete array look like?"*

---

### Solution

So your code should probably look like

```
// Declare and allocate the array
GameEntry[] scoreArray = new GameEntry[4];

// Set elements at indices 0-3
scoreArray[0] = new GameEntry(10);
scoreArray[1] = new GameEntry(100);
scoreArray[2] = new GameEntry(1000);
scoreArray[3] = new GameEntry(10000);

// Iterate the array
for (int i = 0; i < scoreArray.length; i++) {
    // Access the element at index i
    GameEntry currentObject = scoreArray[i];

    // Print some info about the object
    System.out.println("Current object is: " + currentObject);
    System.out.println("It has a score of: " + currentObject.scores);
}
```

---

### Note on printing objects

If you print an object like

```
// GameEntry@15db9742
System.out.println(currentObject);
```

it will call `currentObject.toString()`, a method that every object has (since it's part of the `Object` class which every class implicitly extends). If you don't overwrite this method it will fallback to the default implementation of the `Object` class which prints the class name and some code that identifies the object in the current JVM instance.

Here's how you could overwrite it

```
class GameEntry {
    // Other stuff
    ...

    @Overwrite
    public String toString() {
        return "GameEntry[score=" + scores + "]";
    }
}
```

Now the statement will print it like

```
// GameEntry[score=10]
System.out.println(currentObject);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. That is very close to working but the output is a little off. It's coughing up this: "Current Object is: GameEntry@15db9742
It has a score of: 10
Current Object is: GameEntry@6d06d69c
It has a score of: 100
Current Object is: GameEntry@7852e922
It has a score of: 1000
Current Object is: GameEntry@4e25154f
It has a score of: 10000"

Comment: @KWMuller That is what I expected. What did you expect? :) Are you confused by the `GameEntry@...` stuff? If you print an object it will call `toString` on the object. If you didn't overwrite this method it will fallback to the default implementation stated in the class `Object` which prints the name of the class and some code that identifies the object in the current JVM instance.

Comment: Thanks, man. I understand Arrays a lot better now. We got there in the end! xD

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is going to help you but I tried to give you an idea of how to store objects in arrays.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // If you know the number of objects you're going to store
    int definedSize = 10;

    // Create your array like this
    Object[] objArray = new Object[definedSize];

    // If you don't then use an ArrayList
    ArrayList<Object> objList = new ArrayList<Object>();

    // And use this method to get an array instead of a list
    objArray = objList.toArray();
}
```